# Apache not redirecting as expected

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

I have a virtual host set up on Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu server 18.04

The setup is made of a .conf file for port 80 that contains a redirect to https and a .conf for port 443 that contains all the configuration for the site (like cache, custom 404 and 500 and so on).

I want the same configuration to be ok if the user types the address with or without trailing www

The https part works well.
The http to https redirection works fine with www
The http to https redirection doesn’t work without www

My redirect rule is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

What’s wrong with this? I don’t get where I am wrong, can you help me?

EDIT: after some testing I have verified that this bug applies only to Firefox on iOs and not to Safari on iOs or from desktop

Comment: So the redirection does not work but what happens instead? Is there a default configuration besides the `<VirtualHost>`? Is there another `<VirtualHost>` definition? If the `<VirtualHost>` does not contain both `www.example.com` and `example.com` then the redirect would not work because the `<VirtualHost>` definition does not serve the request.

Comment: The vhost definition is for server name www.example and sever alias example.com. What happens is that Apache serves http:// example.com while for www serves https://www.example.com

Comment: www.example  ??  you mean www.example.com?  Did you clear the Firefox cache?